# insert or update with single button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how to insert and update data in database(sql server) with single button in vb.net i tried but not get the result.
here is my code.......

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Try
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim query As String
        Dim n As Integer
        n = 0
        sqlcom1 = New SqlCommand("select * from mydatabase.masters")
        sqlcom1.ExecuteReader()
        sqlcom = New SqlCommand("select * from mydatabase.masters")
        sqlcom.ExecuteReader()
        reader = sqlcom1.ExecuteReader
        reader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader
        sqlcom = New SqlCommand("Update masters SET EmpName=@EmpName, Age=@Age, Address=@Address where Empid=@Empid", conn)
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@EmpName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox3.Text
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@Empid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox1.Text
        sqlcom1 = New SqlCommand("insert into masters(Empid, EmpName, Age, Address) values(@Empid, @EmpName, @Age, @Address)", conn)
        sqlcom1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Empid", TextBox1.Text)
        sqlcom1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", TextBox4.Text)
        sqlcom1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", TextBox3.Text)
        sqlcom1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox2.Text)
        conn.Open()
        While reader.Read
            n = n + 1
        End While
        If table.Rows.Count = n Then
            sqlcom1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ElseIf table.Rows.Count = n + 1 Then
            sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error" + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code properly\

Comment: *"but not get the result"*. That's too vague a description. Please explain EXACTLY what happens and EXACTLY how it differs from what you expect. Also, you MUST have debugged your code before asking a question here.  If you don't know how to set a breakpoint and step through code in the debugger, you should research that now.

Comment: i want to insert data in table and update the data with the same button in vb.net. i am using sql server as database.

Comment: The search term you need for google is "t-sql merge example". [SQL Server MERGE statement usage and examples](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5373/sql-server-merge-statement-usage-and-examples/).

Answer (score 0):

Using block ensures that your connection object is closed and disposed even if there is an error.
Normally I put comments in line but the code got so cluttered that had to move most of them up here. I hope you can figure out where they belong.

`Dim reader As SqlDataReader` - Unused

`Dim query As String` - Unused

`Integer`s are automatically initialized to zero

Pass the query and the connection to the constructor of the command.

Your connection string will tell SQL Server what database to use. It is not necessary in the query.

Apparently all you want is the count, not all the data.

This query is exactly the same as sqlcom1
`Dim sqlcom As New SqlCommand("select * from mydatabase.masters", cn)`
`sqlcom.ExecuteReader()`
You did this twice
`reader = sqlcom1.ExecuteReader`

Not necessay, we already retrieved the count

```
        `While reader.Read
               n = n + 1
           End While`
```

I made the assumption that table was a DataTable populated at some other time. Using the count as comparison to the count in the table is not a great way to determine if the command is Insert or Update but it might work as long as database and table were not used with a DataAdapter that updated the database.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Try
        Dim n As Integer
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Dim sqlcom1 As New SqlCommand("select Count(*) from masters", cn)
            cn.Open()
            n = CInt(sqlcom1.ExecuteScalar) 'n is now the number of rows in the database table
            Dim sqlcom As New SqlCommand
            sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@EmpName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
            'Age is not a good idea to enter in a database. It changes over time.
            'Enter the birth date and calculate the age as needed.
            sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
            sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            If table.Rows.Count > n Then
                'Normally EmpId would be an auto increment (identity) field
                'and would NOT be included in an insert.
                sqlcom.CommandText = "insert into masters(EmpName, Age, Address) values(@EmpName, @Age, @Address)"
            Else
                sqlcom.CommandText = "Update masters SET EmpName=@EmpName, Age=@Age, Address=@Address where Empid=@Empid"
                sqlcom1.Parameters.Add("@Empid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
            End If
            sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error" + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

On second thought, forget the whole thing. Use a DataGridView and a DataAdapter. Then you can just use Update and it will update, insert and delete.